# Groovy spock where block loop n times

Tags: loops, groovy, where-clause, spock

How to do simple for loop in where block in groovy spock

```
for(int i = 0; i<=10;i++){
     //test
}
```

I remember there is a way, just forgot and can't find resource for it.
Thanks ahead.

Comment: figured out my self: where id << (1..10)

Comment: If you found it ,then close your question, or answer it.

Comment: @user1947415 Please make an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Since this has been viewed 300 times as of my reading this. I'll try to improve the quality of the answer.

The where: block is for parameters only. Void methods don't make sense in that context and don't work like you'd expect, if they work at all.

`10.times {closure}` actually returns null because it doesn't return anything from your closure

`1..10` works (like the comments above state). It creates an [IntRange](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/IntRange.html) object that can be iterated over.

`[1, 2]*5` also works, if you don't care what the value is. This creates the list [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2].  Side note: You should probably skip the where: block and use `#.times{action you wanted to do}` if you don't really care what the passed value is.

The lesson to be gleaned here is that it doesn't really matter what you do. Spock's where: block will iterate over any Collection you pass it using the << operator, if you accidentally pass your parameter using = it will send the entire list at once.

**Bonus Code**
Getting a list of n random integers:

```
(1..10).collect{Integer it ->
    it = new Random().nextInt()}

(1..10).collect{new Random().nextInt()}

[new Random().nextInt()]*10
```

Comment: +1 for the hint about using `<<` instead of `=`. If you want to use a range for the values writing `n << 1..10` won't compile. But it works as expected when adding some paranthesis: `n << (1..10)`